# How to use shinyFiles package within Shiny Modules - Namespace Issue?

Tags: r, namespaces, shiny

I'm having trouble using the "shinyFilesButton()" and "shinyFilesChoose()" functionality within modules in R shiny.

I believe my issue is related to the namespace functions ("ns()") that effectively create new, unique ids within the modules.

**Where do I put the ns() call within the shinyFiles functions? How do I handle this issue on the server side?**

I've mocked up an example, with code shown below.  The app just selects a file and tells you the info on what you selected. <strike>Note that currently no ns() calls are used with any shinyFiles functions. (I've tried wrapping the shinyFilesButton()'s id in the ns(), but then it doesn't match with the shinyFileChoose.)</strike>

<strike>Currently, this app below will show me files, but only in the root directory. I can't delve deeper into other directories. Additionally, the select button will highlight, but nothing will happen when used.</strike>

**Edit:** I've update the code with an attempt at using the namespaces, per suggestions in the comments. I'm using the ns() function in the shinyFilesButton() call (ui side) and nothing in the server side.

Now I can't see *any* files when using the file chooser.

Any help?

Below is my code for the app.r file:

```
#App.R
#Demonstrate issues with ShinyFiles and namesspaces in modules

library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

source("shinyFiles_module.R")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #module Way
  callModule(sample,
             id="testid",
             root_dirs=c(root_on_mac="/Users/Ryan/Desktop/"))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    h2("Module Way"),
    sample_UI(id = "testid",
              label = "shiny file test")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And for the module:

```
#Sample shinyFiles Module
#trying to get File path using ShinyFiles within a Module

library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

#Settings UI function:
# Module UI function
sample_UI <- function(id, label = "Shiny file test") {
  # Create a namespace function using the provided id
  ns <- NS(id)

  #begin UI (wrap all input/ouput in ns() call)
  tagList(
    strong("Selected Location: "), verbatimTextOutput(ns("file_path")),
    shinyFilesButton(
      id=ns("get_file_path"), 
      label="Click Here to Select", 
      title="Select a file",
      multiple= FALSE,
      buttonType = "default", 
      class = NULL)
  )
}

# Module server function
sample <- function(input, 
                   output, 
                   session,
                   root_dirs,
                   id_value) {

  shinyFileChoose(input, id="get_file_path", roots=root_dirs, session=session)

  output$file_path <- renderPrint({
    parseFilePaths(roots=root_dirs, input$get_file_path)
  })
}
```

Comment: You'll want to do `id=ns("get_file_path")` I believe

Comment: So i'd need to redefine the ns function within the server side?

Comment: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Comment: Look at the examples, on the UI side all the inputs are wrapped in `ns`. Then on the server side you call them without `ns` and it knows to look in the right namespace.

Comment: When I do that, it can't see _any_ files at all. I'll update the code in main part to reflect this.

Comment: Oh I see, `shinyFiles` works differently than I thought. Will post answer in minute

Comment: If you are still using this package, you should switch to the Github version. Although it has some other issues but did address the module issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change your module to this and your program works:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

#Settings UI function:
# Module UI function
sample_UI <- function(id, label = "Shiny file test") {
  # Create a namespace function using the provided id
  ns <- NS(id)

  #begin UI (wrap all input/ouput in ns() call)
  tagList(
    strong("Selected Location: "), verbatimTextOutput(ns("file_path")),
    shinyFilesButton(
      id=ns("get_file_path"), 
      label="Click Here to Select", 
      title="Select a file",
      multiple= FALSE,
      buttonType = "default", 
      class = NULL)
  )
}

# Module server function
sample <- function(input, 
                   output, 
                   session,
                   root_dirs) {
  ns <- session$ns
  shinyFileChoose(input, id=ns("get_file_path"), roots=root_dirs, session=session)

  output$file_path <- renderPrint({
    parseFilePaths(roots=root_dirs, input$get_file_path)
  })
}
```

Comment: So that works now, but I still can't dive into directories; I'm stuck in whatever root I pass to it. Any idea why?  Also thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Have you ever gotten that to work outside of a module?

Comment: It works fine outside of the module. I'm not sure what the issue is. For the time being i'll just let my code be messy

Comment: Hello Carl, I know this question is ancient, but I'm having the same problem @bigfoot56 had. I can't dive into directories. Do you have any idea why that is?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and I resolve it by following Carl's suggestion:

- use ns() in ui
- remove ns() in server

I am using R3.6.1 and it works. In R3.4 it has problem navigate into the subfolders.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

#Settings UI function:
# Module UI function
sample_UI <- function(id, label = "Shiny file test") {
  # Create a namespace function using the provided id
  ns <- NS(id)

  #begin UI (wrap all input/ouput in ns() call)
  tagList(
    strong("Selected Location: "), verbatimTextOutput(ns("file_path")),
    shinyFilesButton(
      id=ns("get_file_path"), 
      label="Click Here to Select", 
      title="Select a file",
      multiple= FALSE,
      buttonType = "default", 
      class = NULL)
  )
}

# Module server function
sample <- function(input, 
                   output, 
                   session,
                   root_dirs,
                   id_value) {

  shinyFileChoose(input, id="get_file_path", roots=root_dirs, session=session)

  output$file_path <- renderPrint({
    parseFilePaths(roots=root_dirs, input$get_file_path)
  })
}
```