# shinyFiles package within module

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having trouble using the shinyFiles package with module. When i'm using it without module it works fine. When i'm using it within module i can't dive into directories (other threads have no positive answer) :

```
#' @export
dirModule = function(input, output, session, fileRoot = NULL) {
  root = c(C = "/")
  shinyFileChoose(input, session$ns('files'), roots = root, session = session)
  shinyDirChoose(input, session$ns("directory"),  session=session, roots = c(home = '/home', root = '/'), filetypes=c(''))
  shinyFileSave(input, session$ns("fileSave"), roots = root, session = session)

  observeEvent(input$files, { print(parseFilePaths(root, input$files)$datapath) })
  observeEvent(input$directory, { print(parseDirPath(root, input$directory)) })
  observeEvent(input$fileSave, { print(parseSavePath(root, input$fileSave)$datapath) })
}

#' @export
dirModuleUI = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)

  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      shinyFilesButton(ns('files'), label='File select', title='Please select a file', multiple=T),
      shinyDirButton(ns("directory"), label="Directory select", title = "Select directory", FALSE),
      shinySaveButton(ns("fileSave"), label = "File save", title = "Save file as", filetype=list(text='txt'))
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: It seems `shinyFiles` [uses modules internally](https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles/blob/master/R/filechoose.R#L164). Therefore you might be able to resolve your issues by using the ids directly (`shinyFileChoose(input, 'files', ...)` etc). See [this discussionn](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/issues/133) about a similar issue in shinyjs

Comment: I digged a bit deeper. Seems like your code works with the cran version of `shinyFiles` (which I just installed). If you are using the github version, you need to omit the `session$ns` when assigning ids as shown [here](https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles/pull/58)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved by using the Github version.

You can first install devtools package by `install.packages('devtools')` and then use `devtools::install_github("thomasp85/shinyFiles")` to install the latest shinyFiles package.

After that, just get rid of all the session$ns call in your module server function.

Answer (score 0):

Similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747129/how-to-use-shinyfiles-package-within-shiny-modules-namespace-issue/)

It is namespace issue. I stuck here multiple times in different R version and here is the solution in R 3.6.

I cannot get it work in R 3.4 because it always have problem navigate into subfolders.

```
#' @export
dirModule = function(input, output, session, fileRoot = NULL) {
  root = c(C = "/")
  shinyFileChoose(input, 'files', roots = root, session = session)
  shinyDirChoose(input, "directory",  session=session, roots = c(home = '/home', root = '/'), filetypes=c(''))
  shinyFileSave(input, "fileSave", roots = root, session = session)

  observeEvent(input$files, { print(parseFilePaths(root, input$files)$datapath) })
  observeEvent(input$directory, { print(parseDirPath(root, input$directory)) })
  observeEvent(input$fileSave, { print(parseSavePath(root, input$fileSave)$datapath) })
}

#' @export
dirModuleUI = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)

  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      shinyFilesButton(ns('files'), label='File select', title='Please select a file', multiple=T),
      shinyDirButton(ns("directory"), label="Directory select", title = "Select directory", FALSE),
      shinySaveButton(ns("fileSave"), label = "File save", title = "Save file as", filetype=list(text='txt'))
    )
  )
}
```